# "org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG"

Tags: android

I am developing an application which uses KSOAP2 with Android 2.0. I am 
getting this error:

> "org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG"

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 3):

Could you post the full error?

Look out for the following type of error as I received:

```
WARN/System.err(2330): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope}Envelope (position:START_TAG <h1>@1:4 in java.io.InputStreamReader@47ff3050)
```

The h1 tag is from `<h1>404 Not Found</h1>` so in my case, the webservice was down. Perhaps your webservice is rejecting your version 1.2 soap request with something equally unparsable

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say but the Exception might be due to malformed XML being passed to the Parser.  It's possible that you're not initialising parser correctly and so it can't see any XML.

Can you **edit** your question add the code you have which uses the Parser.

Answer (score 1):

i also got same error and i found 2 reasons behind it, first your URL is not correct second you are using wrong method name,,, recheck it and try...